# Should I always insert "and" between two verbs in imperative mode?

Tags: verbs, bare-infinitive, imperatives, verb-stacking

As far as I understand, the word *and*  is usually inserted between two verbs used in imperative mood  in English. For example, “Go and make me a drink.”

How obligatory is this? Can I claim that it is ungrammatical (or at least less typical) to have to consecutive verbs in imperative mood?

Also, what about the phrase “Go make me a drink”?  Should I treat *go* and *make* in this phrase as two imperatives?

Comment: Saying something like “Go make me a drink” is distinctive as part of American English in particular.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The verb ***go*** can take a bare infinitive following. So can ***come***. (Edit: And sometimes, so can ***run***.)

**Examples:** You can *go get* your hair cut or *come get* your supper, you can *go see* a movie or *come see* what I’ve got, you can *go wash* you car or *come wash* your hands, and you can *go plow* the field or *come milk* the cows with me. Or you can just plain *go hang*.

This is all perfectly normal.  Here are some OED citations of this:

> - 1813 Jane Austen Lett. (1884) II. 216 ― Your Streatham and my Bookham may go hang.
> - 1831 S. Lover Paddy the Piper, Leg. & Stor. Irel. 151 ― There’s an iligant lock o’ straw, that you may go sleep in.
> - 1912 Pedagogical Seminary XIX. 96 ― A rebuke to pride with the notion of ‘get out’,··‘Go jump in the lake.’
> - 1922 Joyce Ulysses 750, ― I dont like a man you have to climb up to go get at.
> - 1968 Globe & Mail (Toronto) 17 Feb. 35 (Advt.), ― Now there is polish as well as boyish personal appeal. Go see.
> - 1968 Encounter Sept. 22/1 ― Go hit your head against the wall.
> - 1969 A. Glyn Dragon Variation vii. 216 ― Let’s go get ourselves a drink.

And similarly with *come*:

> - 1803 Scott ‘Bonnie Dundee’, ― Come fill up my cup, come fill up my can, Come saddle my horses and call out my men.

All those are different than *going **to** see the doctor* or *coming **to** believe* his story, because they don’t take *to*.

---

### Edit

As I wrote in a comment, the verb ***run*** can sometimes do the same thing as ***come*** and ***go*** do.

**Examples:** *Run tell* your mother. *Run find* your father. *Run get* your gun. *Run ring* the dinner bell.  *Run close* the gate.  *Run fetch* the doctor. *Run grab* your hat. *Run throw* it over the edge.

When you have more than one verb stacked up like this, it’s the last one that counts. Any earlier ones just change the aspect.  Contrast:

- *Run go get* your father.
- *Go run* this down to your father.
- Here, *come run* this down to your father for me.

In all those, it’s the last verb that is what is really happening, either getting or running.  The pair ***run go*** seems to occur with some frequency, and takes yet another verb following it.  Here’s [one recent example](http://books.google.com/books?id=84RspqYTUE0C&pg=PA112&lpg=PA112&dq=%22run+go+find%22&source=bl&ots=LkjXcriJ4g&sig=K0FMQkPVgmmdhgunfQ0kd0Y7Ra4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=6Y5zUOXgKe-CyAHRk4HIDg&ved=0CGAQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=%22run%20go%20find%22&f=false):

> “Alright then. I’m just gonna run go find my mom and let her know that I’ll be late getting in tonight,” Jennifer said before kissing Brant’s cheek. “I’m sure they’re together, so I’ll tell your mom too.” Jennifer smiled.

That’s ***am going to run go find***, which is a huge whole lot of stacked verbs, but still it’s the last one the one that tells you what sort of main action is happening here.

---

*What good is sitting 
            alone in your room

            **Come hear** the music play

            Life is a cabaret old chum

            Come to the cabaret


            **Come taste** the wine

            **Come hear** the band

            **Come blow** a horn
 
            Start celebrating right this way

            Your table’s waiting*

Comment: I don't think the "run" examples work as well as "come" and "go" but I LOVE LOVE LOVE the lyrics from "Cabaret" as an example!

Comment: Would "do try this" or "do go on" qualify as another exception? Also, "do go try on that dress" for three verbs in a row.

Comment: Going out on a limb with "do go try to eat those green eggs" for four verbs without an "and" although it's essentially saying "eat those green eggs". It might be cheating, since you can probably keep connecting verbs with "to".

Comment: I am going to run go help find something.

Comment: All the examples of "go" you've listed are imperatives or infinitives. But I've seen it used in the present too: "If something bad happens to them, we go help them", but never for the 3ps *"he goes help them".

Comment: Other than in poetic or lyrical form, the routine omission of "and" is not nearly as common in Britain as it is in America.

Answer (score 4):

English definitely requires an "and" between imperatives, except in certain cases. The phrase "Go [imperative]" is somewhat idiomatic, which is why "Go fuck yourself" or "Go have fun" are perfectly grammatical. However, no other verbs that behave this way are coming to mind. In most other situations, the 'and' is obligatory.

For example, "Sit and eat your vegetables" sounds much more natural than "Sit eat your vegetables."

Comment: oh, "go have fun", I've forgot about this one)))

Comment: There is at least one other similar verb: "come find me", "come show me", "come sit by me", "come play with me" and so on.

Comment: "Come see," like certain phrases with "go," is also correct, though perhaps idiomatic. On the other hand, "Come and get it!" at mealtimes, would not sound right without the "and."

Comment: @shipr  I think that's a metrical consideration, rather than a grammatical one.

Comment: @StoneyB Yes, that's right.  "Come get it" works, too.  Some other examples of this type occurred to me: "Run tell your mother," for example.  Are these all special cases due to their commonness?  Or is there a rule to govern them?

Comment: @StoneyB: Why should "metrical considerations" require *"Come **and** get it!"*, when they don't apparently apply so strongly with, for example, ["Come walk with me"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22come+walk+with+me%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)?

Comment: @FumbleFingers  They don't *require* it; but Where Ah Cum Frum, ***C - o - o - m - e  an g - e - e t it***, was yelled out the back door across several yards, and the two trochees, with a cadence on the second, gave it its characteristic rhythm. I assume (but I don't know your folkways) that the iambic "Come walk with me" calls for a gentler delivery.

Comment: The Del Vikings sang _Come Go With Me_ in the 1950s:              Come, come, come, come,
Come into my heart,
Tell me, darlin',
We will never part;
I need you, darlin',
So come go with me.

Comment: It makes sense that if _go_ is one exception, _come_ would be another, since those two words often go hand-in-hand, in a sense. I'll be interested to see if anyone comes up with another example, besides _come_ and _go_.

Comment: Also "[Go Tell It on the Mountain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_Tell_It_on_the_Mountain_(song))"

Comment: You absolutely must look up "come and get it Peter Russel Clarke" on youtube or other. It was a long running, but only five minute each, cooking segment on Australian TV in the eighties. Surely it's going to replace Gangnam Style. sorry for the spam. Try condition your hearing.

Comment: @tc: Go get out of here! Nice job.