# Is it customary or grammatical to drop ‘to’ in “I’m not going to go look for it”?

Tags: verbs, infinitives, bare-infinitive, verb-stacking

There was a scene a thirty-something wife refuses to go looking for the wedding ring her husband lost in a courtyard when she was asked by her husband over the phone, in the fiction titled “The Lost Order” appearing in New Yorker magazine (January 7).

> “I think I lost it when I was in the courtyard with Monkey [their 
>   pet dog]. I’m sorry to put this on you, but would you mind taking a
>   look around for it?” - - -
>
> “**I’m not going to go look for it**,”
>
> I find myself saying into the phone. It’s not really a decision, it’s
>   more like discovery.”

I noticed that there is no ‘to’ or ‘and’ used in “I’m not going to go look for it.”

Is it customary or grammatical not to bring ‘to+inf’ or 'and' after ‘go.’ 
Is it customary to say “go play baseball,” “go see movie” “go buy pumpkin” “go swim to the pool” or "go help someone."?

Comment: 'Go play baseball' would be far more common than 'go play cricket'. In the UK, _go_ catenates quite often with the to-infinitive, but more often with the 'and-infinitive': _we have decided to go and play cricket on Thursday_. In the US, _go see **a** movie_, _go buy **a** pumpkin_ and _go swim **in** the pool_ would be very common.

Comment: Yes, this is quite customary. In fact, it sounds awkward to say something like "I'm going to go *to* swim at the pool". It's a little bit better with "and" ("I'm going to go *and* swim at the pool"), but it sounds vastly more natural to leave out both. (And if you want to sound even closer to a native speaker, you pronounce "going to" as "gonna", so there's not even a "to" there.)

Comment: Yoichi, would you care to add an "american-english" or "british-english" tag, or even both, to indicate the point of view which should be addressed in any answer? There is a distinct transatlantic difference.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should I always insert "and" between two verbs in imperative mode?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/85155/should-i-always-insert-and-between-two-verbs-in-imperative-mode)

Comment: It's grammatical to say "I'm going to {go see **a** movie / go buy **a** pumpkin / go (**swimming at** / swim **in**) the pool / go help someone [CHOOSE ONE]". Most American native-speakers would add **and** after "go": "I'm going to {go **and** see a movie / go **and** buy a pumpkin go **and** help someone [CHOOSE ONE]". But I suspect that few would say "I'm going to go **and swim in** the pool". It's pleonastic to add "and" or "to", sounds terrible to me (unlike to most AmE speakers), & adds no value or meaning. But spoken English doesn't come with a style manual.

Comment: Also related: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/95032/2085

Comment: @Andrew Leach: Unless the OP has some special reason for wanting to restrict answers to the US or UK context, the fact that usages may differ is no good reason for flagging the question with either or both tags. Besides which, Yoichi himself might be ill-advised to focus on *either* of them here, considering he's got Australian Anglophones a lot closer to home!

Comment: @Bill: Are you saying that the addition of _and_ (admittedly a rather illogical substitute for the infinitive marker _to_) or _to_ itself is pleonastic and terrible-sounding between _go_ and _swim_ but not between _go_ and _see_, _go_ and _buy_, or _go_ and _help_? _Go_ followed by a bare infinitive is very unusual in the UK (though 'Go fly a kite!' has caught on). We do make liberal use of _phase structures_, where two verbs really convey a single or two intertwined 'actions': go swimming / go fishing / go dancing / go hiking / go riding / go playing football /  come shopping / kneel praying.

Comment: @Edwin: Most of the time, adding the _and_ does nothing but add an unnecessary word. _Let's go see_ says the same thing to me as _Let's go **and** see_ in one less word. I think of & use  _go see_ as a 2-word verb. One of the skills a technical editor must have is being able to cut unnecessary words to meet word-count restrictions in journal article abstracts & text. I'm a bit obsessive-compulsive about this point, I know, & out of step with the majority of native speakers. But, as I said, "spoken English doesn't come with a style manual". Brevity isn't always best, I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This form is common in American English.  The equivalent in standard English is "go *verb*-ing" or "go and *verb*".

Comment: I think you’ll find that the linked-to answers go into this in detail.