# Is "you will come experience Louisiana weather" correct?

Tags: grammar, expressions

Many times I have heard people use two verbs with the same subject.

I know that it is possible to use *come* + an action verb without using "to" in between. However, I have frequently heard "can you come get me" or "you will come experience...", and in my mind, I go - there should be a "to" between those two verbs. But I am not a native speaker of English and I may be wrong. So, I need your help to answer this question.

Thank you.

Comment: The example in your title sounds unlikely in any context I can easily imagine, even if we *do* include the (syntactically necessary, imho) infinitive marker ***to***. Perhaps what you intended to say might be better expressed as *You will come to **appreciate** Louisiana weather*.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, indeed, I could have thought of a better example for "come experience". But you did answer my question. Thanks again.

Comment: In the cited context, ***come to*** is a syntactically "standard" usage implying ***undergo a change of attitude [over time]***, and anything else is effectively "ungrammatical". In the slightly different context of something like *You should come [**to / and / (nothing)**] visit me in Louisiana*, different "rules" apply - ***to*** is "correct, but starchy", ***and*** is "correct *and* widespread", and *nothing at all* is simply a widespread colloquial usage that wouldn't get you any marks in a formal English test.

Comment: Of related interest: *[Can the word “go” be used as a helping verb?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/446272)* and *[Should I always insert “and” between two verbs in imperative mode?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/85155)*, plus *[Why don't we say “We're going eating”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/463830)* and *[“Get something” vs. “Go get something”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/133107/)* among others.

Answer (score 2):

come and go:

come and see or come see

go and see or go see

come and go can be followed by another verb. Either with an "and" between them or not.

- Come and see me when you get to town.
- Come see me when you get to town.
- Come to see me when you get to town.

Those all mean the same thing, basically. The use of "to" is more for a purpose, if one wants it to be: Come see me to get your books back.

However, if you want to sound ***invitational*** or ***inviting***, the to would be left out.

- Come [and] see the wonders of Louisiana.
- Go [and] see the birds in that nature preserve. You'll love it.

The square brackets mean you can put the "and" in or leave it out.

Originally, I suspect only: Come and [verb] would have been correct. But nowadays usage is very often without the and. I don't know the history of this grammatical point.

Question: Will you come and experience x? Or Will you come experience x? Both are fine. Those are proper interrogative forms. There are times we use a statement as question in English by use of intonation, but it does not work well here.

Answer (score 0):

The verb 'come' collocates with 'experience'. There is no need to add 'to'!
We can say:
Will you come experience Louisiana weather, yourself?